# Form not submitting when button is pressed in Next.js/Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, shadcnui

```
"use client";

import { Product, Image, Color, Category, Size } from "@prisma/client";
import { Heading } from "@/components/ui/heading";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Trash } from "lucide-react";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  Form,
  FormMessage,
  FormDescription,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { AlertModal } from "@/components/modals/alert-modal";
import ImageUpload from "@/components/ui/image-upload";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";

const formSchema = z.object({
  // name: z.string().min(1), -- in prisma schema we have label and imageUrl, not a name.
  name: z.string().min(1),
  image: z.object({ url: z.string() }).array(),
  price: z.coerce.number().min(1),
  categoryId: z.string().min(1),
  colorId: z.string().min(1),
  sizeId: z.string().min(1),
  isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
  isArchived: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
});

type ProductFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema> & { images: Image[] };

interface ProductFormProps {
  initialData:
    | (Product & {
        images: Image[];
      })
    | null;
  categories: Category[];
  colors: Color[];
  sizes: Size[];
}

export const ProductForm: React.FC<ProductFormProps> = ({
  initialData,
  categories,
  colors,
  sizes,
}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const params = useParams();
  const router = useRouter();

  const title = initialData ? "Edit product" : "Create product";
  const description = initialData ? "Edit a product" : "Add a product";
  const toastMessage = initialData ? "Product updated" : "Product created.";
  const action = initialData ? "Save changes" : "Create";

  const form = useForm<ProductFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: initialData
      ? {
          ...initialData,
          price: parseFloat(String(initialData?.price)),
        }
      : {
          name: "",
          images: [],
          price: 0,
          categoryId: "",
          colorId: "",
          sizeId: "",
          isFeatured: false,
          isArchived: false,
        },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data: ProductFormValues) => {
    try {
      console.log("aaa");
      setLoading(true);
      if (initialData) {
        await axios.patch(
          `/api/${params.storeId}/products/${params.productId}`,
          data
        );
      } else {
        await axios.post(`/api/${params.storeId}/products`, data);
      }

      router.push(`/${params.storeId}/products`);
      toast.success(toastMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Something went wrong.");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
      router.refresh();
    }
  };

  const onDelete = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await axios.delete(
        `/api//${params.storeId}/products/${params.productId}`
      );

      router.push(`/${params.storeId}/products`);
      toast.success("Product deleted.");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Something went wrong.");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
      setOpen(false);
      router.refresh();
    }
  };
const onInvalid = (errors: any) => console.error(errors);

  return (
    <>
      <AlertModal
        isOpen={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        onConfirm={onDelete}
        loading={loading}
      />
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <Heading title={title} description={description} />
        {initialData && (
          <Button variant="destructive" size="sm" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
            <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
      <Separator />
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, onInvalid)}
          className="space-y-8 w-full"
        >
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="images"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Images</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <ImageUpload
                    value={field.value.map((image) => image.url)}
                    disabled={loading}
                    onChange={(url) =>
                      field.onChange([...field.value, { url }])
                    }
                    onRemove={(url) =>
                      field.onChange([
                        ...field.value.filter((current) => current.url !== url),
                      ])
                    }
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="name"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={loading}
                      placeholder="Product name"
                      {...field}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="price"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Price</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      disabled={loading}
                      placeholder="9.99"
                      {...field}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="categoryId"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Category</FormLabel>
                  <Select
                    disabled={loading}
                    onValueChange={field.onChange}
                    value={field.value}
                    defaultValue={field.value}
                  >
                    <FormControl>
                      <SelectTrigger>
                        <SelectValue
                          defaultValue={field.value}
                          placeholder="Select a category"
                        ></SelectValue>
                      </SelectTrigger>
                    </FormControl>
                    <SelectContent>
                      {categories.map((category) => (
                        <SelectItem key={category.id} value={category.id}>
                          {category.name}
                        </SelectItem>
                      ))}
                    </SelectContent>
                  </Select>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="sizeId"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Size</FormLabel>
                  <Select
                    disabled={loading}
                    onValueChange={field.onChange}
                    value={field.value}
                    defaultValue={field.value}
                  >
                    <FormControl>
                      <SelectTrigger>
                        <SelectValue
                          defaultValue={field.value}
                          placeholder="Select a size"
                        ></SelectValue>
                      </SelectTrigger>
                    </FormControl>
                    <SelectContent>
                      {sizes.map((size) => (
                        <SelectItem key={size.id} value={size.id}>
                          {size.name}
                        </SelectItem>
                      ))}
                    </SelectContent>
                  </Select>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="colorId"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Color</FormLabel>
                  <Select
                    disabled={loading}
                    onValueChange={field.onChange}
                    value={field.value}
                    defaultValue={field.value}
                  >
                    <FormControl>
                      <SelectTrigger>
                        <SelectValue
                          defaultValue={field.value}
                          placeholder="Select a color"
                        ></SelectValue>
                      </SelectTrigger>
                    </FormControl>
                    <SelectContent>
                      {colors.map((color) => (
                        <SelectItem key={color.id} value={color.id}>
                          {color.name}
                        </SelectItem>
                      ))}
                    </SelectContent>
                  </Select>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="isFeatured"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="flex flex-row items-start space-x-3 space-y-0 rounded-md border p-4">
                  <FormControl>
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={field.value}
                      onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                    ></Checkbox>
                  </FormControl>
                  <div className="space-y-1 leading-none">
                    <FormLabel>Featured</FormLabel>
                    <FormDescription>
                      This form will appear on the home page.
                    </FormDescription>
                  </div>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="isArchived"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="flex flex-row items-start space-x-3 space-y-0 rounded-md border p-4">
                  <FormControl>
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={field.value}
                      onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                    ></Checkbox>
                  </FormControl>
                  <div className="space-y-1 leading-none">
                    <FormLabel>Archived</FormLabel>
                    <FormDescription>
                      This form will not appear anywhere in the store.
                    </FormDescription>
                  </div>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>
          <Button disabled={loading} className="ml-auto" type="submit">
            {action}
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
      <Separator />
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductForm;
```

I am trying to create a product in the database when the form is submitted, and the data for the product is based on the form data. However, when i press the button to submit the form, The OnSubmit function is not being ran. I added a console log inside of the function to verify if the function is being ran and nothing is appearing in the console. No errors, nothing.

EDIT: i added the onInvalid function to my submit, which console logs an error: "
{image: {…}}
image
:
{message: 'Required', type: 'invalid_type', ref: undefined}
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
"

it seems like a zod related error, and it says "invalid_type". What could possibly be wrong in my code

Comment: You don't need to add a <form /> when you are importing the Form component. Use only the Form component from "@/components/ui/form" and add a "onSubmit" handler on the Form component.

Comment: Tried, didn't work.The Form component is a shadcn ui component, and it is more like a wrapper rather than an element, and it is specified in the documentation that an another plain html <form> should be nested inside of it so we can add submitting functionalities. Also, i added some useful information in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to modify your `formSchema` as per bellow:

```js
const formSchema = z.object({
  // name: z.string().min(1), -- in prisma schema we have label and imageUrl, not a name.
  name: z.string().min(1),
  images: z.object({ url: z.string() }).array(),
  price: z.coerce.number().min(1),
  categoryId: z.string().min(1),
  colorId: z.string().min(1),
  sizeId: z.string().min(1),
  isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
  isArchived: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
});
```

Changes:

- Replaced `image` with `images`